Error while using script to unattended install publisher server
I have created publisher installation script using following article https://github.com/NunoLinhares/Web-8.5-Quick-Install
I got below error.
Interact: Error: Access Management configuration is required for the Experience Space feature.
when I installed manually it worked fine without any issues. can someone suggest where should I configure Access Management for Experience Space

is it expecting Access Management check as part of parameters? Same script worked for CMS and publisher in single machine installation

That's impressive that @Nuno's quick install script still mostly "just works." :-)

Issue resolved after passing ACCESS_MANAGEMENT_URL parameter
